# MongoDB: adding fields based on partial match query - expression vs query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have one collection that I'd like to query/aggegate. The query is made up of several parts that are OR'ed together. For every part of the query, I have a specific set of fields that need to be shown.

So my hope was to do this with an aggregate, that will **$match** the queries OR'ed together all at once, and then use **$project** with **$cond** to see what fields are needed. The problem here is that **$cond** uses *expressions*, while the **$match** uses *queries*. Which is a problem since some query features are not available as an expression. So a simple conversion is not an option.

So I need another solution.. 
- I could just make an aggregate per separate query, because there I know what fields to match, and them merger the results together. But this will not work if I use pagination in the queries (limit/skip etc).
- find some other way to tag every document so I can (afterwards) remove any fields not needed. It might not be super efficient, but would work. No clue yet how to do that
- figure out a way to make queries that are only made of expressions. For my purpose that might be good enough, and it would mean a rewrite of the query parser. It could work, but is not ideal.

Comment: What code? just some lines of aggregate code will not really help anyone I guess..

Answer (score 1):

So This is the next incarnation right here. It will deduplicate and merge records and finally transform it back again to something resembling a normal query result:

```
db.getCollection('somecollection').aggregate(
[
  {
    "$facet": {
      "f1": [

        {
          "$match": {
            <some query 1>
        },
        {
          "$project: {<some fixed field projection>}
        }

      ],
        "f2": [
        {
          "$match": {
            <some query 1>
          }
        },
        {
          "$project: {<some fixed field projection>}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
    {
    $project: {
          "rt": { $concatArrays: [ "$f1", "$f2"] }
    }
  }, 
  { $unwind: { path: "$rt"} },
  { $replaceRoot: {newRoot:"$rt"}},
  { $group: {_id: "$_id", items: {$push: {item:"$$ROOT"} } }},
  {
    $project: {
          "rt": { $mergeObjects: "$items" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: {newRoot:"$rt.item"}},
]
);
```

There might still be some optimisation to be, so any comments are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I found an extra option using **$facet**. This way, I can make a facet for every group opf fields/subqueries. This seems to work fine, except that the result is a single document with a bunch of arrays. not yet sure how to convert that back to multiple documents.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so now I have it figured out. I'm not sure yet about all of the intricacies of this solution, but it seems to work in general. Here an example:

```
db.getCollection('somecollection').aggregate(
[
  {
    "$facet": {
      "f1": [

        {
          "$match": {
            <some query 1>
        },
        {
          "$project: {<some fixed field projection>
        }

      ],
        "f2": [
        {
          "$match": {
            <some query 1>
          }
        },
        {
          "$project: {<some fixed field projection>
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
        $project: {
              "rt": { $concatArrays: [ "$f1", "$f2"] }
        }

  }, 
  { $unwind: { path: "$rt"} },
  { $replaceRoot: {newRoot:"$rt"}}
]
);
```

Comment: Next problem: the queries can give you the same records, so need to be deduplicated (or better merged).  Fun stuff..